# What app.UseMigrationsEndPoint does in .NET Core Web Application Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I created a new .NET Core Web Application from Visual Studio and I got this piece of code generated in startup class:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    // ***
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    // ***
}
```

What actually does this line `app.UseMigrationsEndPoint()`?
[The official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.migrationsendpointextensions.usemigrationsendpoint?view=aspnetcore-5.0) are not helpful at all:

> Processes requests to execute migrations operations. The middleware will listen for requests made to DefaultPath.

What's the default path? What to POST to it? What will it actually execute? Does it have any optional parameters? Is it protected somehow?

Comment: What's unclear? Docs refer to a static `MigrationsEndPointOptions.DefaultPath` field that is a default value for the `Path` property on the same class. Typin in that property should allow you to see the value or a peek in the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/src/MigrationsEndPointOptions.cs#L18)

Comment: You're right, everything can be found in the source. I guess I was used to MSDN days when MS documentation covered everything. RTFM became RTFS :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you maybe already seen from the linked documentation page, it comes from EF Core. The exact code, that will be run, can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/src/MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.cs).

It checks if the used database has any pending migrations and will apply them if needed. That's it.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'm still quirked as to how an ASP.NET website can be up and running while db-migrations are not fully applied. What I mean to say is, aren't db-migrations supposed to be run before the website is up? How can one introduce a new db-migration to the runtime while the website is up and running. And even if that was possible wouldn't it be dangerous? I guess there's a scenario I must be missing.

Comment: To support that mentioned scenario, this code exists. This means you deploy your new version to productive slot which causes a restart of the application. On this restart the migration will be applied and after that the new code starts to run. Creating a minimal downtime.

Comment: Also, as long as schema changes are only additive and don't contain any new key constraints (e.g. you add a simple column to a table), EF can use the *old design* and simply can't see or use this column which means if your code adds new entities they have to support nullity or the SQL schema must provide a meaningful default value in the transition phase.

Answer (score 44):

This `app.UseMigrationsEndPoint()` is actually a very handy tool in development.

As we develop, we add entities to the db context, or modify ones we have. We run `dotnet ef migrations add <NameOfMigration>` as usual, and that would generate migration files. I personally would typically run `dotnet ef database update` when the `migrations add` command succeeds. However, with `app.UseMigrationsEndPoint()`, I don't have to manually run `dotnet ef database update`.

So, we try to build and run our app in development. The browser loads our app, but the `database update` did NOT yet happen as we might expect.

However, if we tried to access a page or an API call that needed to access a table that hasn't yet been updated, we get a special page - not an error page - but one that lists all the migrations that haven't yet been applied.

Surprisingly, there is a button marked "Apply Migrations" (or something like that). We would click that, then our database would be updated according to the migrations not yet applied. We would then reload the page, and the browser will then display the page as we expect. We can check the tables in `SQL Server Object Explorer` or other tool, and we will see those migrations reflected.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one

Comment: I'm wondering why this is only for development and not production? I am struggeling with a freshly deployed mvc app - it doesnt create the DB structure and I can't run the migration from the Azure Cloud Shell CLI so I am tempted to use this in general - whats the downside on this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the *exact* line of code on GitHub that initializes the `DefaultPath` field:

[Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/src/MigrationsEndPointOptions.cs:18](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/dca391766976fcd5ea880db6088266a8f0c388a8/src/Middleware/Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/src/MigrationsEndPointOptions.cs#L18)

There you can see that the value is set to `"/ApplyDatabaseMigrations"`

```
public class MigrationsEndPointOptions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The default value for <see cref="Path"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static PathString DefaultPath = new PathString("/ApplyDatabaseMigrations");

    // ...
```

Comment: I added this answer because it gives the *exact* source code location *and* the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the default path? ...

`/ApplyDatabaseMigrations`
in aspnetcore main as of 2023-02-08 (Feb).

> ... What to POST to it? What will it actually execute? Does it have any optional parameters? Is it protected somehow?

I think these are answered above or in comments.

Comment: Just because they don't include it in the docs doesn't mean that choice is appropriate nor that we have to be just as unhelpful here.